# Get XML data from PHP file url

Tags: php, xml, get

I currently have a script (phpSysInfo) that checks my server information. They have provided a file called xml.php - when I load this file in the URL, the content of an .xml file is generated.

My question is, how can I get data from this file/URL with PHP?

I have tried using simpleXML, but it doesn't seems to can open a .php file. Therefore I am stuck.

Comment: Paste the code you have tried and "doesn't work."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to execute the PHP file. Doing `file_get_contents('xml.php')` will simply read the raw PHP code.

Something like:

```
ob_start();
include('xml.php');
$data = ob_get_clean();

$xml = new SimpleXML($data);
```

would do the trick. The `include()` will execute the PHP script. And the ob_* functions will capture its output for you, returning it into the $data variable.

Comment: Using this, how can I then echo out data with PHP from the XML file? I don't quite understand. Sorry

Comment: This: **                    ob_start();
                    include('phpsysinfo/xml.php');
                    $data = ob_get_clean();
                    $xml = new SimpleXML($data);
                    
                    print($xml);**

Doesn't output anything. I need to know how to echo out specific XML strings / data

Comment: $xml will be an object. you can't just print it out. $data will have the raw xml generated by the file.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to say print $xml. When printing out $data, nothing happens.

Comment: `echo strlen($xml);` if that prints a number other than 0, you've got xml data and just aren't seeing it in the window. If it's zero, then your xml.php isn't outputting anything and you'll have to figure out why.

Comment: Not sure why, but this line: $xml = new SimpleXML($data); seems to be stopping the rest of the code. When I have that line, the page content just stops.

Comment: then look in your error logs, and/or turn on error_reporting/display_errors in PHP (search http://php.net for details on that). You should always have them on while debugging/developing anyways.

Comment: I have turned on PHP error reporting. Although, nothing is displayed.